# Pandas string match negative lookahead not working

Tags: python, regex, pandas, regex-lookarounds, regex-negation

I want to set all values in my Pandas dataframe that do not match the desired format to NaN.

Example of the undesired format:

[image: Example of the undesired format]

Code

```
df['Anfang L1'] = df['Anfang L1'].str.replace(r'(?!\D{3}.\d{2})', '')
```

The regex expression is working without the negative lookahead.
The regex expression is also working with the negative lookahead in the str.match function.

```
df[df['Anfang L1'].str.match('(?!\D{3}.\d{2})')]
```

Thanks for helping me guys.

PS: I have also tried the following

```
df['Anfang L1'].replace(to_replace=r'(?!\D{3}.\d{2})', value='new', inplace=True)
```

Comment: Format your code properly

Comment: What do you need? You say your regexps work well. However, the dot must be escaped to match a literal dot. Please post reproducible code snippet to repro the issue, and also the expected result.

Comment: Just in case, while you are still working on a reproducible example, try `df['Anfang L1'].replace([r'^\d{2}\.\d{4}$'], np.nan, regex=True, inplace=True)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew This worked, please post this as a solution, so that I can flag this question as solved. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I posted [an answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60439171/3832970) with an explanation

Comment: I see you want to follow the negation path, see [my updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60439171/3832970) with just one step to achieve what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
df['Anfang L1'].replace([r'^\d{2}\.\d{4}$'], np.nan, regex=True, inplace=True)
```

If you need to match all but `^\D{3}\.\d{2}$` pattern use

```
df['Anfang L1'].replace([r'^(?!\D{3}\.\d{2}$).*'], np.nan, regex=True, inplace=True)
```

The `^\d{2}\.\d{4}$` pattern matches

- `^` - start of string
- `\d{2}` - two digits
- `\.` - a dot
- `\d{4}` - four digits
- `$` - end of string

The other pattern means:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!\D{3}\.\d{2}$)` - right there, and up to the end, there should not be

  - `\D{3}` - three non-digit chars
  - `\.` - a dot
  - `\d{2}` - two digits
- `.*` - all the rest of the string.

Comment: Thank you very much
I tried your solution as well and it worked!
My question would be why i have to do the 
   .*
at the end

Comment: @FrederikLedermüller With `.*`, you *consume* the string that does not match the pattern in the lookahead (lookaheads are *non-consuming* patterns, i.e. the texts they match are not added to the match buffer and thus are not affected by the replacement operation).

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the definition for regular expression.

A **Negative Lookahead** `A(?!B)` is meant for matching all `A`'s **not** followed by `B`.

The final objective is to set all the entries which do not match `\D{3}\.\d{2}` to `NaN`.

One way to do it,

```py
# Get a `series` of values which is true if it matches my format
match_my_correct_format = df['Anfang L1'].str.contains(r'\D{3}\.\d{2}')

# Set all rows which don't match my format to null
df[~match_my_correct_format] = np.nan
```

Comment: But I just want that one column to be set to np.nan

Comment: just change the last line to `df['Anfang L1'][~match_my_correct_format] = np.nan`

Comment: I have found out that solution that was posted first only solved one malformated case but your solution worked for all. Thx man I have tried to solve this for two days. Your final comment was necessary!